# How to download and view images from the new Firebase Storage?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am able to upload images to Firebase Storage but I am having trouble downloading them. This is my code to download images:

```
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
let localURL : NSURL! = NSURL(string: "file:///Documents/co.png")
// i also tried let localURL : NSURL! = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("file:///Documents/co.png")

func download() {
    let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://project-5547819591027666607.appspot.com")
    let imageRef = storageRef.child("co.png")

    let downloadTask = imageRef.writeToFile(localURL) { (URL, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving - Optional("An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.")

**Also once I get them downloaded How would I view that image?**

**For trying to see if the image was downloaded I created a UIImageView and set an outlet for it in storyboard called "imageView" then set the downloaded image to the UIImageView.**

```
self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Comment: your url seems wrong for the file. try `fileURLWithString` make sure you can load image from that url first in the app then proceed to upload

Comment: I am trying to download

Comment: see the part about downloading the url of the file [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url) . Download the url and then just use that url in Alamofire or NSURLSession yourself. that will be easier to do as Alamofire will do things like caching and thing better.

Comment: could you show me some code to support your suggestion please

Comment: Can you post the full error message (like you did below)? There have been a few file system permissions errors where you don't actually have permission to write to the appropriate directory, oddly enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

first getting reference to the image you want to download using

```
let reference = FIRStorage.storage().reference("uploads/sample.jpg")
```

If you know the size of image is low - like 1-2 mb max . download the image in memory

```
reference.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print(error)
  } else {
     let myImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)    
  }
}
```

This will be the quickest and easy way to download directly from Firebase Storage.

However there are cases when you want the progress blocks and certain other things like caching. In such cases you could use any third party like Alamofire to download the image from the url you get from Firebase Storage.
To get the url do something like this

```
reference.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
     print(URL)
     // download image using NSURLSession or Alamofire
  }
}
```

Comment: that seemed to work because now i am getting 'optional(Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13021 "User does not have permission to access gs://project-*******.appspot.com/(null)." UserInfo={ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Developer credentials required."
  }
}, ResponseErrorCode=403, NSLocalizedDescription=User does not have permission to access gs://project-5547819591027666607.appspot.com/(null).})'

Comment: read about permissions https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#overview

Comment: Changing your Security Rules or using Auth will solve the issue, though the `/(null)` is troubling since it looks like you're not actually downloading anything (are you trying to download something at the root reference?).

Comment: my fault i copied in his line of code .reference("uploads/sample.jpg") instead of my reference. It is now downloading the image.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald how would I go about downloading all photos at the same time? Do i have to submit a request for each one?

Comment: Like if I have a backgrounds folder, downloading all 10 images into a tableview for the user to choose one. Do i have to submit a request for each image or can i request for the folder?

Comment: You have to download each individually, there's no concept of a batch download.